# Dual to group algebra of a finite group as a Hopf Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-homomorphism, hopf-algebras

I have a group algebra of a finite group $G$ over $\mathbb{C}$ and $Fun(\mathbb{C}[G])$ represents the linear functions on $\mathbb{C}[G]$. 
$\mathbb{C}[G] \otimes \mathbb{C}[G]$ denotes the tensor product of $\mathbb{C}[G]$ as vector spaces with multiplication $(g_1 \otimes g_2)*(g_3 \otimes g_4) = (g_1g_3 \otimes g_2g_4)$.

Assume that we have the comultiplication $g \mapsto g \otimes g$, counit $g \mapsto 1$ and antipode $g \mapsto g^{-1}$. These operations make $\mathbb{C}[G]$ a Hopf algebra.

I want to show that algebras $\mathbb{C}[G]$ and $Fun(\mathbb{C}[G])$ are dual to each other by bilinear form $<f,g>=f(g),\  f \in Fun(\mathbb{C}[G]),\  g \in \mathbb{C}[G]$;

But for that I need to represent the image of comultiplication of $f \in Fun(\mathbb{C}[G])$:
 $f(g_1,g_2) \in Fun(\mathbb{C}[G] \otimes \mathbb{C}[G])$, (which is $f(g_1*g_2)$), as $X(g_1) \otimes Y(g_2) \in Fun(\mathbb{C}[G]) \otimes Fun(\mathbb{C}[G])$,
 but have no idea how to do that.

Comment: I'm sorry, fixed the question.

Comment: Typically people use the letter $G$ for a group, not the group algebra itself, no? And isn't the set of linear functions on a vector space literally the definition of the dual vector space? What does this have to do with group algebras at all - isn't it just a question about dual vector spaces and tensor products, or are you assuming the dual of a group algebra has extra structure like a coalgebra?

Comment: I fixed the letters. Yes, I assume, that $\mathbb{C}[G]$ is Hopf Algebra with canonical comultiplication $g \mapsto g \otimes g$ and so on. I will add it to the question.

Comment: In the future please don't post your question until you've provided enough context.